# how to open video file in code blocks using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to open a video file using Open-CV in code blocks. I have integrated Open-CV in it successfully but can’t understand how to open a video file. There are examples on the Internet  but they get different main argument programs which give an error:

```
int main (int arg c, char *arg v[])
```

and include arguments which i don't know how to use in code blocks.

Comment: We spell it `argc` and `argv`, no whitespace. I suggest you start with an introductory C++ book, rather than an OpenCV project. The latter may prove too intimidating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example:

```
#include "highgui.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cvNamedWindow( "Example", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("sample.mkv");
    IplImage* frame;
    while (1) {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if (!frame)
            break;
        cvShowImage( "Example", frame);
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if (c == 27)
            break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow ( "Example" );
}
```

You'll write your video file name in **cvCreateFileCapture** function.

For argv-argc question , I recommend you this tutorial.

http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html

Edit for C++ API

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**) {
    namedWindow("Sample Video", 1);
    VideoCapture cap("sample.mkv");
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;
    Mat frame;
    while (1) {
        cap >> frame;
        imshow("Sample Video", frame);
        char c = waitKey(33);
        if (c == 27)
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks [karlphillip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176769/karlphillip)

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of the C API. It's deprecated and it's going away soon.

Comment: can you please tell me how to access a file like image file as program arguments in code blocks

Comment: You'll write **argv[1]** instead of **"sample.mkv"** and add file name argument when executing.
Ex: ./program.cpp sample.mkv